# How to compress an Image with k clusters and c dimensional vectors

Tags: image, cluster-analysis, k-means

Image compression with k-means: k-means clustering algorithm can be used for image compression. The image is divided into nonoverlapping  ×  windows and these  2 -dimensional vectors make up the sample. For a given , we do -means clustering. The reference vectors and the index for each window is sent over the communication line. At the receiving end, the image is then reconstructed by reading from the table of reference vectors using the indices. Write the computer program that does this for  ∈ {4, 8, 16} and  ∈ {20, 40, 60}. For each pair of (, ), (1) save the compressed images as “.jpg” or “.png”, and (2) calculate the reconstruction error. Each pair of (, ) will have a reconstruction error and a compression rate, so you will have 9 pairs of rates. Use Python library “scikit-learn.clsuter”. The image may be RGB-colored, so you can flatten each window into a vector of length  ×  × 3 using “ndarray.flatten(‘F’)” in Python and then convert it back to a  ×  × 3 matrix when reconstructing the compressed image.

Looking for an explanation on the above question.

Answer (score 0):

K is the numer of colors in one sample
Compression rate is 1 -  new size / old size
Reconstruction error = average distortion calculated from k means

Algorithm is like this :
1 Divide image in blocks of c×c
2 For each block, calculate k mean and assign color to each pixel
3 calculate compression rate

RGB colors are like (255,255,255) . Each pixel needs 8 bits.
Original size = image size * 3 * 8 bits

In compressed version you need the number of c×c partitions , k colors for each partition and storage space of k colors for each partition

4 calculate error . Error is average of distortion error from each block